# Logback - using appenders per method, rather then class

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have a class with several methods. I would like each method to output to a different log file. With a logback.xml file like this, it logs ALL logging calls from the class.

```
<logger name="com.mincom.ellipse.conversion.BatchConverter" level="INFO">
   <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
```

How do I get per method logging calls. I'm sure it's very simple, but I cannot seem to see the answer in the doco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't used logback, but in log4j and others you can setup loggers with any name you like. Using the classes package and name is just a convention. So I'd setup Multiple loggers in your class, something like this:

```
Logger logA = LogFactory.getLogger("LogA");
Logger logB = LogFactory.getLogger("LogB");

public void methodA() {
    logA.debug(...);
}
public void methodB() {
    logB.debug(...);
}
```

And then in your logback setup ...

```
<logger name="LogA" level="INFO">
   <appender-ref ref="FILE-A" />
</logger>

<logger name="LogB" level="INFO">
   <appender-ref ref="FILE-B" />
</logger>
```

Should work. Probably needs some tweaking :-)